# display months on time axis with d3

Tags: d3.js

I am replicating the Githubs contributions heatmap

[image]

I have successfully created and colorized the heatmap, but I am having problems creating the time scale that would only show the months or even better month and year. Any tips on how to display months? This is what I have so far:

[image]

```
let dateRange = d3.timeDay.range(new Date(2022, 0, 1), new Date()).map(e => { return { "date": e, "value": Math.floor(Math.random() * 15) } });


const cellSize = 16
const countDay = d => d.getUTCDay()
const timeWeek = d3.utcSunday;

const colorFn = d3.scaleSequential(d3.interpolateHcl( "#2be5ba", "#1d846c")).domain([
  Math.floor(d3.min(dateRange, (o)=>o.value)),
  Math.ceil(d3.max(dateRange, (o)=>o.value))
])

d3.select("#heatmap")
  .append("svg")
  .append('g')
  .selectAll('rect')
  .data(dateRange)
  .join('rect')
  .attr("width", cellSize - 1.5)
  .attr("height", cellSize - 1.5)
  .attr("x", (d, i) => timeWeek.count(d3.timeYear(d.date), d.date) * cellSize + 10)
  .attr("y", d => countDay(d.date) * cellSize + 0.5)
  .attr("fill", d => {
    if(d.value == 0){
      return "#e5edf3";
      return "aliceblue";
    }else{
      return colorFn(d.value);
    }})
  .attr("stroke", d => {
      if(d.value == 0){
        return null;
        return "#dbe2e8";
        return "aliceblue";
      }else{
        return null;
      }})
  .attr("rx", "2")
```